# C# getting its own class name

Tags: c#, reflection

If I have a class called `MyProgram`, is there a way of retrieving "*MyProgram*" as a string?

Answer (score 1057, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.GetType().Name
```

Comment: @Thomas - True, although the OP will have to use reflection to do so.  This may or may not matter.

Comment: you could also create a static method that creates an instance and returns the Name property. Definitely easier than using Reflection.

Comment: If you're in a static method then the *developer* knows what the name of the type is. You can just type it in as a string in the source code.

Comment: @EricLippert: If you type the name in, the compiler won't catch it if the class is renamed.

Comment: @Halvard: First, if the static method is in the current type then the name is optional; if you're worried about it changing, omit it. Second, Visual Studio will automatically give you a smart tag when you rename a class that renames all instances of it. And third, if you're renaming a class then odds are good you're going to have to make a lot of changes in a lot of places already.

Comment: @EricLippert You are right.  Any ***new*** version of Visual Studio or ReSharper will catch the strings with the same name as the class being renamed.  My previous comment is just some old, now useless knowledge ...

Comment: Can the answer be updated to also show how to get the `SimpleName`?  #noob

Comment: @EricLippert The reason I want to detect the name of the class (and even method) that I'm in is for logging purposes - I guess I could write the stacktrace, but it seems excessively verbose. If I'd like to write something to log, and have the log include "MyNamespace.FooClass.BarMethod" at the beginning of the WriteLine automatically, is there a good way to do this?

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey: Yes! This feature was added in C# 5. The documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: @Halvard: ... and in C# 6 you can use the new `nameof` operator.

Comment: @EricLippert  Finally :)

Comment: @EricLippert That works great for detecting the calling method name, but logging the filename and line number isn't what I'm looking for, because then I'd have to checkout the same source tree as the application that Trace'd something to log. I'm still looking for a good way to detect the namespace & class name.

Comment: @EricLippert What about this? Is there any reason this wouldn't be a good answer? ```var meth = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(); string methName = meth.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + meth.Name;```

Comment: I assume this wouldn't work if you use it in release and apply obfuscation

Comment: You can also do `typeof(ThisClass).Name`

Comment: @Bennik2000 - In case of an inherited class, your suggestion gives the name of the base class!

Comment: @dotnetguy, the discussion above was about the static methods. Static methods are not inherited in C#. So in 2017 you can always use nameof() in static methods and GetType() in non-static.

Comment: @Konstantin, 1) My comment is in response to Bennik2000, which is seemingly a comment on an answer to a question that does not mention static, my comment still holds. 2) inside a class you can always do nameof() irrespective of it being static or instance: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y9XzEB

Comment: 1) Ah, I see now 2) I have updated fiddle to show you what I mean.

Comment: can exclude "this" as well

Comment: I use the method in this Answer as it works for inheritance, if a method on A uses this to return "A", then if inherited by class B it will return "B".

Answer (score 304):

I wanted to throw this up for good measure. I think the way [@micahtan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2113076/2350083) posted is preferred.

```
typeof(MyProgram).Name
```

Comment: This is actually better, because: 1. It will work in static context 2. It is compile time computed, so it doesn't cost like reflection

Comment: @Gilbert This is not better than the accepted answer by micatan, which works regardless of the name of the class. The only advantage of this over simply `"MyProgram"` is that the compiler will catch it if the name of the class is changed.

Comment: @JimBalter It has multiple advantages: 1. Static context. 2. The type portion will not be re-evaluated by the CLR each time - it will be written to the MSIL. 3. It protects you from someone declaring a new "GetType()".

Comment: That's not a response to what I wrote -- *The only advantage of this over simply "MyProgram"*

Comment: @JimBalter Correct, the advantages over "MyProgram" are the that the compiler will catch it if the name of the class is changed OR if you got it wrong the first time.

Comment: I think that there is clearly no better or worse. Which is better depends solely on circumstance. That's why we can do both.

Comment: If you want to get inherited class name and this call is in the parent then it won't work.

Comment: This has the disadvantage of having to reference the type explicitly, which makes it less easily reusable.

Comment: +1 this is the best answer for me and worked for a template type in a generic method which is what I was looking for

Comment: In C# 6.0 or later you can do `nameof(MyProgram)`.

Comment: But you already have the name of the class. You demonstrate that by having to write it's name. You could just as easily write 'string str = "MyProgram";' Either way requires you to manually update that line of code anytime the code is copied. That completely defeats the purpose in my opinion. Reflection will give you code that is universal.

Answer (score 283):

With C# 6.0, you can use the [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) operator:

```cs
nameof(MyProgram)
```

Comment: Great stuff; also works with type _members_ (such as methods and properties) and even variables - see [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 146):

Although micahtan's answer is good, it won't work in a static method. If you want to retrieve the name of the current type, this one should work everywhere:

```
string className = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
```

Comment: Nice catch, although I think my method is preferred in this case.

Comment: This Won't work for non-virtual methods, as it will return the name of the type that the method is declared and implemented in, (possibly up the inheritance chain), not the concrete type of the instance you are actually executing the code from.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in the DNX (Dot Net Execution) framework. They removed the GetCurrentMethod() method and left only GetMethodFromHandle().

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to get the name of the concrete class currently executing code called from a virtual function in a descendant.

Answer (score 21):

If you need this in derived classes, you can put that code in the base class:

```
protected string GetThisClassName() { return this.GetType().Name; }
```

Then, you can reach the name in the derived class. Returns derived class name. Of course, when using the new keyword "nameof", there will be no need like this variety acts.

Besides you can define this:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static string NameOf(this object o)
    {
        return o.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

And then use like this:

```
public class MyProgram
{
    string thisClassName;

    public MyProgram()
    {
        this.thisClassName = this.NameOf();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

For reference, if you have a type that inherits from another you can also use

```
this.GetType().BaseType.Name
```

Answer (score 10):

Use this

Let say Application **Test.exe** is running and function is **foo()** in **form1** [basically it is *class form1*], then above code will generate below response.

```
string s1 = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
```

This will return .

```
s1 = "TEST.form1"
```

for function name:

```
string s1 = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

will return

```
s1 = foo
```

Note if you want to use this in exception use :

```
catch (Exception ex)
{

    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace );

}
```

Comment: DeclaringType is declared `[Nullable(2)]` so you get an warning when null check are active.

Comment: @Martin, please explain your comment. I don't get it?

Answer (score 10):

`this` can be omitted. All you need to get the current class name is:

```
GetType().Name
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be used for a generic class

typeof(T).Name

Answer (score 3):

Get Current class name of Asp.net

```
string CurrentClass = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToString();
```

Comment: DeclaringType is declared `[Nullable(2)]` so you get an warning when null check are active.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the call name attribute. However, currently, there is no attribute class that returns the class name or the namespace of the calling method.

See: [CallerMemberNameAttributeClass](http://The%20easiest%20way%20is%20to%20use%20the%20call%20name%20attribute.%20%20See%20%5Bhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.8%5D)

```
public void DoProcessing()
{
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");
}

public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}

// Sample Output:
//  message: Something happened.
//  member name: DoProcessing
//  source file path: c:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CallerInfoCS\CallerInfoCS\Form1.cs
//  source line number: 31
```