# Getting class name inside the class itself

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# getting its own class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113069/c-sharp-getting-its-own-class-name)

For Visual Studio, I want to create a class template and use a string field that holds the name of a class itself. Is it possible?

For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public string TAG = GetClassName(this);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When talking about non-static methods use [Object.GetType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) which returns the exact runtime type of the instance (a reference to an instance of the [Type Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42892f65.aspx)):

```
this.GetType().Name
```

When talking about static methods, use [MethodBase Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.aspx) and its [GetCurrentMethod Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx) :

```
Type t = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
//t.Name
```

However, see [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081612/net-determine-the-type-of-this-class-in-its-static-method) for more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetClassName(object item)
{
  return typeof(item).Name;
}
```

Comment: Obviously this does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
this.GetType().Name
```

[Type.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name.aspx) -> Gets the name of the current member.