# System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(); give ".ctor"

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, methodbase

Stats:  Visual Studio 2015 C#
        Selenium Webdriver 2.53.1
        Internet Explorer 11

Trying to add the Method Names to my reporting for clarity.
I am using

```
    MethodBase m = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
```

I then call

```
 m.Name
```

expecting to see the method name but instead in my reporting it calls **".ctor()"**

Any advice on how to call the actual method name instead?

Comment: Are you calling it from a constructor?

Answer (score 2):

`ctor()` is the default constructor for a class. That means you are calling `GetCurrentMethod()` while the class you are calling it from is still being constructed.

You might also want to get the class name (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2113099/4894733)):

```
string className = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
```

Comment: Or that the code provided is a field in the class- the field initializer would be called during class construction.