# Current class alias

Tags: c#, syntax, keyword

Is there in language anything like `curclass` to reference current class name without hardtyping it any time again and again?
As example something like `typeof(curclass).GetMethod(nameof(curclass.MyMethod))` instead of `typeof(MyPrettyClass).GetMethod(nameof(MyPrettyClass.MyMethod))`.

Update: it's not just about name, but about alias.

Comment: Do you mean `this.GetType()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# getting its own class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113069/c-sharp-getting-its-own-class-name)

Comment: It all will work in runtime, not compiletime like `nameof` does. And what about static classes?

Answer (score 0):

There is no alias  for current type or typedef equivalent in C#. I would suggest two possible solutions though:

1- Use `using` statement at top of the file:

```
using MyNamespace.MyPrettyClass = curclass;
```

You need to repeat this for every class though as this works only at the scope of current file.

2- Define a variable of type `Type` like this and use it:

```
private static Type curclass = typeof(MyPrettyClass);
```

The variable doesn't have to be static though but static allows to use in contexts when there is no specific instance.
Also you have to repeat this construct for every class.