# Get really current class name in Page_Load method - ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Solution Explorer
[image: Solution Explorer]

I can get current method name, but currently I can't get really current class name.
From reference: [C# getting its own class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113069/c-sharp-getting-its-own-class-name), accepted answer is `this.GetType().Name`.
Test.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string currentMethodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name; // "Page_Load"
            string currentClassName1 = this.GetType().Name; // "test_test_aspx" // How to get "Test" only?
            string currentClassName2 = this.GetType().FullName; // "ASP.test_test_aspx" // How to get "Test" only?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1672994, it's working, but it's not common code. For example: I must use `nameof(AnotherClass)` in AnotherClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
  string className = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
```